# Defined X and Y Axis in pChart 2.0

Tags: php, charts, line, pchart

I'm using the line graph of pChart for a partograph.

Now, my problem is, I can't define the values for the x and y axis. The y-axis will adjust automatically depending on the data that is set on the graph. This is not what I want.

Please see illustration:

[By default, when no data is to be plotted in the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tci3P.jpg).

[When loaded with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVEmO.jpg).

Notice that the values of the Y-axis changed. What I want is to make the scale of axis from 0 to 10 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the scale manualy. For example:

```
 $AxisBoundaries = array(0=>array("Min"=>0,"Max"=>100));
 $ScaleSettings  = array    
 ("Mode"=>SCALE_MODE_MANUAL,"ManualScale"=>$AxisBoundaries,"DrawSubTicks"=>TRUE,"DrawArrows"=>TRUE,"ArrowSize"=>6);
 $myPicture->drawScale($ScaleSettings);
```

Hope this helps